# Multiple prefixes in CakePHP for API routing

Tags: cakephp, routes

This is turning out to be way harder than it should be. What I want to do:

```
Router::connect('/:api/:version/:controller/:action/*',
    array(),
    array(
        'api' => 'api',
        'version' => '2.0|2.1'
    )
);
```

And have it map to controller actions. Example, have this:

```
http://example.com/api/2.0/users/get/1
```

...map to this in the Users controller...

```
public function api_2_0_get()...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the fact that this is neither supported, nor are you actually using prefix routing. You will either have to connect routes per prefix, like

```
Router::connect('/api/2.0/:controller/:action/*',
    array(
        'prefix' => 'api_2_0',
        'api_2_0' => true
    )
);

Router::connect('/api/2.1/:controller/:action/*',
    array(
        'prefix' => 'api_2_1',
        'api_2_1' => true
    )
);
```

See also **[Cookbook > Development > Routing > Prefix Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)**

or use a custom route class that builds the action name from multiple route elements, something along the lines of

**app/Routing/Route/VersionedApiRoute.php**

```
App::uses('CakeRoute', 'Routing/Route');

class VersionedApiRoute extends CakeRoute
{
    public function parse($url)
    {
        $route = parent::parse($url);
        if (!$route) {
            return false;
        }

        $route['action'] =
            'api_' . str_replace('.', '_', $route['version']) . '_' . $route['action'];

        return $route;
    }
}
```

**app/Config/routes.php**

```
App::uses('VersionedApiRoute', 'Routing/Route');

Router::connect('/api/:version/:controller/:action/*',
    array(),
    array(
        'routeClass' => 'VersionedApiRoute',
        'version' => '2\.0|2\.1' // this is a regex, so don't forget to escape the dots
    )
);
```

See also **[Cookbook > Development > Routing > Custom Route Classes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes)**